# How to prevent backtracking from end-of-string

Tags: regex, perl

I'll start with an example: Say your target string is xyyzyy, and you want to match /^x[yz]*z/ against it. This will match xyyz, after backtracking from end-of-string. However, I don't want it to backtrack if it reaches end-of-string; I want it to fail immediately once it hits end-of-string.

Importantly, I don't control the contents of the regular expression; it is provided by the user. Thus, I'm hoping there's a way to do this that involves merely wrapping or concatenating the user's regular expression with some special construct.

For more detail: I'm trying to write a perl script that reads input in pieces (to avoid slurping a very large file into memory all at once), and matches a given regular expression against those pieces. If the given regex matches to the end-of-string, I will reject the match because if more input had been read, it might have matched more than just that piece (and then I will read more input and try matching again). That case I can reject easily with a negative assertion of $.

But it is also possible for a match attempt to hit end-of-string, then backtrack from there, and eventually match a subset of the input piece, as in my example above. This is the case I'm trying to solve. Referring back to my example above, say the overall input consisted of xyyzyyzabc, but my program only read xyyzyy initially. I need to reject the xyyz match because it should have matched xyyzyyz. Thus, if the match attempt hits end-of-string at all, even if it could backtrack from there to find a match, it needs to fail outright.

I've looked at all of perl's special regex features, which are many, but none seem to offer a possible solution. The possessive constructs looked promising, but I can't force the user to use them within their regex, and furthermore, the user may want non-possessive matching, thus going "all possessive" is not a solution. I thought wrapping the entire expression in (?>...) might work, but it still seems to allow backtracking within the ... subexpression, and seems to only enable possessiveness for the final multiplier, if such exists, thus it will not work in all cases (including the example I've given in this question). I also looked at the backtracking control verbs, but none seem to allow causing outright failure at a position in the target string (such as end-of-string); they only seem to work at positions in the regular expression, and only after all preceding atoms have been matched successfully.

Comment: This sounds like `hitEnd` method from Java's Matcher, though I don't know if Perl supports this.

Comment: `hitEnd` would be perfect, Perl doesn't seem to have any equivalent.

Comment: what o/p do you expect for xyyzyy

Comment: There should be no output; I want the match attempt to fail because it hit end-of-string. Alternatively (although less performantly), I would accept a solution that returned any (subset) match but also somehow communicated that it had hit end-of-string (before backtracking), like Java's `hitEnd`, so that I can reject the match in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WARNING: See Update several paragraphs down for examples of failures of this solution.**

I think I've found the only possible solution to this problem in Perl5. See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=225083, http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=298525, and http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=298971, from 2003/2004, which discuss the problem of matching a regex against a stream. The end result of those threads is an impressively clever solution that has been implemented in http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/File-Stream-2.30/lib/File/Stream.pm.

The solution works by embedding between every pair of adjacent atoms a look-ahead assertion on end-of-string using `\z`, and then immediately forcing the match attempt to fail if the `\z` atom succeeded. If `\z` failed, meaning the current position is *not* at end-of-string, then an empty alternation branch is used to prevent premature failure and allow the match attempt to continue with the next atom (following the embedding), if any.

The exact embedded expression given in the second perlmonks thread I referenced is as follows:

```
(?=\z(?{ die "end of string" })|)
```

You can see they're using a `die()` call in an embedded code block to cause the match attempt to fail if `\z` matched, which means the match attempt must be trapped in an `eval{}` block to catch the error. The pipe on the right provides the needed empty alternation branch to prevent failure if not yet at end-of-string.

The exact expression used in File::Stream is an improvement, I'd say, as it avoids `die()`:

```
(?:\z(?{$End_Of_String++})(?!)|)
```

Here `(?!)` is used to force the match attempt to fail if at end-of-string, and this causes it to fail in the normal way, rather than using `die()` and an `eval{}` block. There is still a need to capture the knowledge of whether the match attempt failed *prior to* end-of-string, or whether it failed *at* end-of-string, as in the latter case more input must be read from the stream and the match must then be reattempted. They solve that problem here with an embedded code block (seems that can't be avoided) to increment a variable that will be accessible after the match attempt has returned. Also, they changed the look-ahead assertion to a cluster, as both branches are zero-width anyway, but that isn't significant.

On a slightly personal note (that may be of help to others), when I was trying to invent solutions to this problem, I originally dismissed the possibility of intercepting the match attempt when it hit end-of-string by adding a special embedding, because I'd been thinking that backtracking only takes place during the matching of a single atom, and you can't intercept the regex engine while it's working on a single atom. It *is* true that you can't intercept the regex engine while it's working on a single atom, but I've now realized that in most cases backtracking does *not* begin *during* the matching of a single atom, but rather it begins *after* the previous atom matched successfully up to a position, and then the immediately following atom fails at that position. Thus, there is an opportunity to intercept the regex engine by embedding an expression between those two atoms. The only case I can think of where backtracking begins *during* the matching of a single atom is a multiplied atom with a non-zero lower-bound (e.g. `a{3}`) where the atom "runs out of characters" that match it, and then must backtrack earlier atom(s). But in that case, if it ends up matching at all after backtracking, it will be guaranteed to have gobbled up all remaining characters up to the furthest point it had originally hit, which was the point at which it had originally failed **[not true -- see failing case #1 below]**. Thus, it is guaranteed to either (1) end up failing completely, which will cause the entire regex to fail **[not true -- see failing case #2 below]**, or (2) successfully match and then allow the following atom to continue from the furthest point it had hit in the target string. Thus, if the regex engine ever touches end-of-string, then there will always be an opportunity to intercept it. That's why the File::Stream solution works; it embeds the end-of-string check between every pair of adjacent atoms, using YAPE::Regex to parse the regex into tokens.

Referring to my earlier example, the `[yz]*` atom successfully matches to end-of-string; backtracking only begins once the `z` atom fails to match at end-of-string. So the embedding between those two atoms would catch it, before the `z` atom even gets a chance to be matched.

There's obviously a nasty performance hit here, as you have to parse the regex into tokens and then concatenate it back together again with lots of extra text due to the embedding, which must be embedded between *every* adjacent pair of atoms. Furthermore, it looks like there can be a lot of redundancy of embedding, due to both (1) the existence of various zero-width atoms supported by Perl regular expressions, which cannot move the position to end-of-string themselves, but would still be returned by YAPE::Regex as tokens and thus would be surrounded by embeddings, and (2) the fact that YAPE::Regex parses non-atoms as tokens; for example, it treats `(` and `)` as tokens, even though those are not atoms, so that adds to the cost.

**Update:** Okay, this is funny. Writing this answer provoked me to think a little more deeply about what might cause this solution to fail, and I've found two such cases. I'll leave the above answer as I wrote it (with some added warnings), because most of it is correct, but add the following:

**Failing case #1: double-backtrack**

There is one case where the backtracking provoked during matching of a single multiplied atom will cause the regex to eventually match prior to end-of-string, and thus the embedding will never get a chance to detect that end-of-string was touched. It's a bit complicated, and difficult to describe in words (example coming in a moment), but it requires a variably-multiplied atom with an upper bound of at least 2 and a range of at least 2 to be followed by a "latching" atom, finally followed by another multiplied atom with an upper bound of at least 2 (this one can be constant-multiplied, and in fact, that makes the example easier). Let's call these 3 atoms the "backtracker", the "latcher", and the "leader". If the stream buffer has sufficient input to match the backtracker and latcher, but *not* the leader, it is possible for the backtracker to backtrack by a character, match, then the latcher to fail to match (because its match position in the target string was pulled back a character), then the backtracker to backtrack by another character, match, then the latcher to match, and finally the leader to match 1 character back from the end-of-string. This will all happen internally during regex engine processing, so the embedding never gets a chance to detect that the end-of-string was encountered, and the final match returned by the match attempt will end 1 character before end-of-string, so it'll look just fine. But more input might have changed the result.

Below I'll present a runnable shell one-liner to demonstrate this. Before I do, let me just show a line I manually added to File::Stream (/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/File/Stream.pm on my current system) to aid in seeing what's going on while File::Stream is running. I added it at line 242, in the `fill_buffer()` function:

```
sub fill_buffer {
    my $self = shift;
    my $length = shift || $self->{read_length};
    my $data;
    my $bytes = read( $self->{fh}, $data, $length );
    return 0 if not $bytes;
    printf("info: read %d/%d bytes: \"%s\"\n", $bytes, $length, $data ); ## added
    $self->{buffer} .= $data;
    return $bytes;
}
```

Below is the demo. You have to have YAPE::Regex and File::Stream to run this, and obviously must manually add the above line if you want to see the exact same output. Note that I'm using Encode and calling `Encode::_utf8_off()` on the RE string because I've found that YAPE::Regex fails on UTF-8-flagged strings (not sure why), which is another limitation of this solution, although it should certainly be fixable in YAPE::Regex.

```
> echo -n xzazaz123| perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; use utf8; use Encode; use File::Stream; my $stream = File::Stream->new(\*STDIN, ("read_length" => $ARGV[0]) ); my $restr = $ARGV[1]; Encode::_utf8_off($restr); $/ = qr($restr); while (my $field = <$stream>) { print("  field: ",$field,"\n"); }' 5 '[az]{0,2}z[az]{2}';
info: read 5/5 bytes: "xzaza"
  field: xzaz
info: read 4/5 bytes: "z123"
  field: az123
```

So, what's happening here is that File::Stream is reading STDIN 5 bytes at a time, and trying to match `/[az]{0,2}z[az]{2}/` against it. The backtracker is `[az]{0,2}` (`{0,2}` is a greedy multiplier, importantly), the latcher is `z`, and the leader is `[az]{2}`. The input is `xzazaz123`.

Now, obviously the correct match would be `zazaz` just after the `x` (note that `x` in the input wasn't really necessary; you can think of it as the "record content" before the "record delimiter" which is being matched by the regex). But because File::Stream gets `xzaza` in its buffer on the initial attempt, the regex engine matches the backtracker against the `za`, then the latcher against `z`, then the leader against the `a`, which exhausts the buffer. This does not satisfy the leader, because it requires 2 characters, and so the atom fails to match. In reality, more input should be read now, but the match attempt is not over yet. The regex engine proceeds to backtrack the backtracker (because it's the only atom in the regex that can be backtracked, due to its variable bound) to 1 character. Thus, it then matches just `z`. The latcher then fails to match the following `a`, so the backtracker is backtracked again to 0 characters. It matches the empty string just before the first `z`, then the latcher matches that `z`, then the leader matches the following `az`. Notice that the entire regex ended up matching *prior* to end-of-string. Thus, upon advancing to the next atom, which would be the embedding, it would have no inkling that end-of-string had been touched, and would pass the match attempt through its empty alternation branch, and finally, the entire match attempt would succeed. Upon receiving the complete match back in userland, there would be no way of knowing if the regex had touched end-of-string. Thus, it is accepted by the File::Stream code, and this is why the first field we get is, incorrectly, `xzaz`.

**Failing case #2: longer-to-shorter alternation**

Another failing case is an alternation group that fails at end-of-string in a prior branch, effectively short-circuiting the entire branch, and then moves on to a subsequent branch which does not touch end-of-string, but ultimately succeeds. Here is an runnable example, which uses similar parameters to my original example, but is different:

```
> echo -n xyyzyyzabc| perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; use utf8; use Encode; use File::Stream; my $stream = File::Stream->new(\*STDIN, ("read_length" => $ARGV[0]) ); my $restr = $ARGV[1]; Encode::_utf8_off($restr); $/ = qr($restr); while (my $field = <$stream>) { print("  field: ",$field,"\n"); }' 5 '([yz]{5}|y{2})z';
info: read 5/5 bytes: "xyyzy"
  field: xyyz
info: read 5/5 bytes: "yzabc"
  field: yyz
  field: abc
```

Here, again, File::Stream is reading STDIN 5 bytes at a time, and this time trying to match `/([yz]{5}|y{2})z/` against it. The input is `xyyzyyzabc`.

Now, obviously the correct match would be from the first branch, as it comes first, which would be `yyzyyz`. But because the initial buffer only has `xyyzy` in it, the first branch fails, as it runs out of characters. An embedding was embedded at the end of the first branch, but it is never reached. The regex engine moves on to the second branch, and it matches the 2 `y`s, then the `z` matches, and so the final complete match is `yyz`. Thus, the first field returned by File::Stream is `xyyz`.

**Conclusion:** So, unfortunately, although it is a very clever trick, and a valiant attempt at solving this problem, I have to recommend that *no one* use this solution, or the File::Stream module. And so, even more unfortunately, it appears that at this point in time there is *no* working solution to the problem of applying a regex to a stream, without slurping in the whole thing at once.

The good news is that if you go to http://www.perl6.org/archive/faq.html, it actually says one of the upcoming features in Perl6 is "incremental regex matching against input streams". But there's no release date yet for Perl6. I guess we just have to wait.

Comment: Incremental regex matching against input streams is still part of the P6 vision. (cf [Larry Wall's very recent comment about how a back-tracking feature is supposed to interact with streams)](http://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2014-10-10#i_9485737). But it's not yet implemented. (cf The "matching streams" red bar in ["compiler features matrix"](http://perl6.org/compilers/features)). And unless some hero steps up and implements it in 2015, matching streams will be dropped for the 2015 "production use" release. (See [my perlmonks comment about this](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1106772).)

Answer (score 2):

Its not a full solution but you can use the (*COMMIT) verb:

perl -Mre=debug -le'my $str="xyyzyy"; $str=~/^x(\z(*COMMIT)|[yz])*z/'

will fails when it hits the end of the string and then backtracks.

Where this is going to be hard is generalizing this to handle all the ways that you can hit the end of the string.

Sorry there isn't an easier solution for this. Its on my todo list to allow $/ to be set to a regex, which would solve this problem in core.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a negative lookahead like so that basically just uses a copy of the regex. I know the user inputs the regex, but can you basically input

```
^(?!x[yz]*z$)x[yz]*z
```

Which is would just be

```
^(?!USEREXPRESSION$)USEREXPRESSION
```

Regexr: http://regexr.com/39ufc

```
xyyzyy - matched
xyyz
xyzz
xyzx - matched
xyzyz
xyzyzq - matched
xyyz
xyzzz
```

Comment: This would not solve the case of backtracking from end-of-string. I don't want xyyzyy to match, because if more input had been read (referring to my original example), then it should have matched xyyzyyz.